# Add different shipping address at customer registration

Tags: magento

I'm trying to get it so a customer can add a shipping address in addition to a billing address at account creation. Right now I am able to have it add the address that acts as the billing and shipping. I am able to copy the address fields for billing but how to do I get it to create two addresses when submitted? How do I get the client side validation to handle the new fields?

Comment: During the checkout process, the customer can already provide a different address as shipping address. You can inspire you of that. But honestly, you should make the account creation shorter as possible if you don't want to lose customers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may be custom coding this which is not the way to go. Instead, do the following:

Open app/design/frontend/default/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml

Around line 78
Before

```
<?php if($this->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
```

Add

```
<?php $this->setShowAddressFields(true); ?>
```

That will add the address collection to the form to the registration page, validate it the same as other forms on site, and insert it as a billing and shipping address for you.

Comment: This is not really what he asked for. He wants the possibility to do this separately. Have one form for billing address and one for shipping address.